# Triangle in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shapes

I'm trying to create a triangle with OpenGL but I see nothing but a white board on my screen.

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>

extern float vertices[3][3] = 
{
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f },
    {  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f },
    {  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f }
};


void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3fv(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[2]);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello Gult");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

What could it be and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) when using a double-buffered window (`GLUT_DOUBLE`). Also, you must clear the depth buffer when the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) is enabled. Use [`glColor3f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml) instead of `glColor3fv` when specifying a color with 3 separate arguments:

```cpp
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[2]);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```